# svn remove nested/inner class java

Tags: java, svn, inner-classes

I suppose the answer to my question is really simple, I haven't figured out that though.
I had a class with an inner/nested class inside. After I decided to remove this class.
The only problem is that now I can't remove it from my svn. If I execute svn status I receive this ouput:

```
?       .directory
?       trunk/.directory
!       trunk/classes/org/evaluation/UserProfilesReader$Query.class
```

I have to delete this file from svn, but if I execute:

```
svn remove trunk/classes/org/evaluation/UserProfilesReader$Query.class
```

I receive this output:

```
D         trunk/classes/org/evaluation/UserProfilesReader.class
```

svn tries to remove the main class and I have to revert this change.

Did anyone have that problem?

Comment: @Giovanni, seriously... you need to add the entire target directory to the ignore list, or face stupid problems like this.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quoting. Run this instead, with the path parameter enclosed within single quotes:

```
svn remove 'trunk/classes/org/evaluation/UserProfilesReader$Query.class'
```

`$` is used by the shell for variables. So without quoting, the shell expands `$Query` to empty string, the filename effectively becoming `UserProfilesReader.class`.

Btw, it's not normal to add build products (`*.class` files and others) to version control.
I recommend to remove the entire `classes` directory, and mark the directory to ignore to avoid adding it to the repository by accident.